# Controller error reporting - errors is null

Tags: grails, error-handling, controller

I'd like to ask general question about right way of error reporting in grails' controller. Pretty common way of doing this seems to be using spring validation errors interface. It is simple, elegant and has good support in GSP rendering:

```
def myAction() {
     ...
     errors.reject(...) // NPE
     ... 
     if (hasErrors()) {
         // handle errors
     }
}
```

But, I've also noticed, that `errors` has `null` value when nor domain objects nor parameters binding are used. Is it grails' bug or am I missing something. In such a case adding any fake `String` (to avoid any binding errors) parameter to action helps a lot:

```
def myAction(String dummyArg) {
     ...
     errors.reject(...) // successful, no NPE
     ... 
     if (hasErrors()) {
         // handle errors
     }
}
```

Of course such a solution is very far from being elegant. How to force `errors` to be always accessible? Is this right way of error reporting if sometimes `errors` is `null`?

Comment: What kind of errors are you trying to report? If they are Domain errors, they should be reported in the Domain; `user.errors.rejectValue(..)`.

Comment: In fact no matters. If I validate some domain instance inside the controller its error reports are also accessible via controller's `errors`. Still don't get what controller's `errors` is, but seems to contain all domain, binding and manually rejected errors.